# The number of times an item was on the list before

Tags: python, list

Dataframe

```
data = {'col1':['a', 'b', 'b', 'c']}

#What I need:
data_with_new_feature = {'col1':['a', 'b', 'b', 'c'], 'col2':[0,0,1,0]}
```

Col2 describes the number of times the item was before on the list. I have it in that order, so I just need to find col2. Col2 reads as follows: 'a' was 0 times before on the list, 'b' was 0 times before on the list, 'b' was once on the list before, 'c' was never on the list before

Any ideas on how to solve this? I tried to use loops but I am sure there is a better way.

Comment: What is the loop that you tried? A loop with a dictionary seems like a natural approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're really using a pandas dataframe (somewhat implied by your question), or if you don't mind switching to pandas, you can use `groupby` and `cumcount`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a', 'b', 'b', 'c']})
df['col2'] = df.groupby('col1').cumcount()
print(df)
```

output:

```
  col1  col2
0    a     0
1    b     0
2    b     1
3    c     0
```

Answer (score 3):

with l beeing your col1 and count_list beeing col2
`d = {}
count_list = []
for c in l:
    if c in d:
        count_list.append(d[c])
        d[c] += 1
    else:
        d[c] = 0
        count_list.append(d[c])
        d[c] += 1`

Answer (score 2):

You can count the occurrences with a dictionary. And just add the current count.

```py
def cumulative_count(values):
    counts = {}
    output = []
    for value in values:
        counts.setdefault(value, 0)
        output.append(counts[value])
        counts[value] += 1
    return output


cumulative_count('abbc')
# [0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

An `O(n)` solution would be to use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to keep track of current counts, then append the incrementing counts to `data` as you iterate it. In this case `n` would be the number of columns in `data["col"]`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = {"col1": ["a", "b", "b", "c"]}

counts = defaultdict(int)
for item in data["col1"]:
    data.setdefault("col2", []).append(counts[item])
    counts[item] += 1

print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
{'col1': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c'], 'col2': [0, 0, 1, 0]}
```

If you indeed need a pandas solution(ambiguous from the question since you've just shown a plain dictionary), then [@jfaccioni](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62409550/the-number-of-times-an-item-was-on-the-list-before/62409759#62409759) has a good answer you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over `col1` elements and count number of occurrences of the elements in sliced `col1` (till the current index):

```
data = {'col1':['a', 'b', 'b', 'c']}
data["col2"] = [data["col1"][:i].count(element) for i, element in enumerate(data["col1"])]
print(data)
# {'col1': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c'], 'col2': [0, 0, 1, 0]}
```